# Array to Calendar-Table

Tags: php, html, arrays, foreach, html-table

I created the following Array ($stuArr) in PHP.
I want to print the Array in an HTML-Table so that I can create a Table like this (Calendar-System):

[image]

The numbers in the table are the dates of the month.
And each user has a own row. I generate the table with this:

```
$days = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);
$days = $days + 2;

echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr>";
for ($j = 0; $j < $days; $j++) {
    echo "<th>$j</th>";
}
echo "</tr>";

//Person
$file = file_get_contents('MOCK_DATA-100.json');
$data = json_decode($file);

//Events
$file2 = file_get_contents('calendar.json');
$data2 = json_decode($file2);

$stuArr = [];

foreach($data as $student) { 
    $id = $student->id;
    $name = $student->name;

    $mark = false;
    foreach($data2 as $cal) {
        if($cal->resource == $id) {
            $start  = new DateTime(substr($cal->start, 0, 10));
            $end    = new DateTime(substr($cal->end, 0, 10));
            $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
            $period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);                    

            $dd         = [];
            if($month == $start->format('n')) {
                foreach ($period as $dt) {
                    if($month != $dt->format('n'))
                        break;
                    $dd[]   = $dt->format("j");
                }
                $stuArr[] = [$id, $dd];
            }
        }
    }
    
}

var_export($stuArr);

foreach($stuArr as $student) {
    $id     = $student[0];
    $dates  = $student[1];

}

echo "</table>";
```

Output of  `var_export($stuArr);`:

```
array ( 0 => array ( 0 => '2', 1 => array ( 0 => '22', 1 => '23', 2 => '24', 3 => '25', ), ), 1 => array ( 0 => '3', 1 => array ( 0 => '23', 1 => '24', 2 => '25', ), ), )
```

Thanks for your help! Regards, Fynn
If you have any question for me or need an explanation of some part of the code, just say it!!!

Error:
[image]

Comment: Important: split data manipulation (loops to collect events per student, json decode) from data presentation (html). add each in separate functions.
1. Student id should be unique. If it is, you should simplify data structure.
2. you can do all what you need with only one loop in events (there you have student id) -> collect all events (dates) per student id.
studentXCalendar= array<days>
studentCalendars = array<key:studentXId, val:studentXCalendar>
at this point you have clean data structure to display:
3. get html from user events: loop by users (not to skip any student)

Comment: @VladimirVukanac Hello, can you give me please an example? The id's of students are unique.

Comment: `$stuArr[] = [$id, $dd];` this is problematic. It can work, but you have to re-loop to pickup by $id. You can do in this line: `$stuArr[$id][] = $dd;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code. I can see you printed o-29 as days, try starting from 1 instead of 0 in the loop.

```
// update inside the Student loop, previous code remains as it is

        foreach($stuArr as $student) {
            
            $dates  = $student[1];
            
            echo "<tr>";
            
            for ($j = 1; $j <= $days; $j++) {

                if(in_array($j, $dates))
                    echo "<td>X</t>";
                else 
                    echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";

            }   
            
            echo "</tr>";           
        
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! I updated my Question, now it looks very strange..

Comment: Updated my answer, try now

Comment: Thanks, now it is working. 2 quick other questions: How is it possible to print each id at the beginning of each row? I added $id = $student[0]; but then it will print only the id's of the student which has an event. 2nd question is that if i create an event like this:   {"start":"2021-09-22","end":"2021-09-22","resource":"2","id":"30"} it wont be dissplay, but a studnt can have a event sometimes only at one day, do you know what i mean and what i can do`?

Comment: I will mark your question as solved, but it would very nice, if you can help me :)

Comment: For two equal dates you can compare the dates for equality, and to print the ID of the student you have to add one table column like <td>ID</td> at the start of each row (<tr>).

Comment: The ID part is working now, but with the equality i am unfamiliar...

Comment: can take a look at the php help pages, search and you will get it

Comment: On which specific position do I have to place the equality-tag?